# Unable to open Dropdowns, Hyperlinks & Hyperlink Buttons on landing Webpage

Tags: html, input, element

I'm experiencing a weird issue with my live website landing page https://indigojobs.in/jobs, users unable to select any of the search filters, hyperlinks and hyperlink buttons. They appear as if they're frozen and not responsive at all. Issue appear a day ago and i'm unable to trace back any relevant changes. I don't even see any script errors. Issue persists in all browsers. All it working pretty nicely for an year but troubling now. Appreciate any help since its severity as hundreds of users are on live. Thanks in advance!

PS: It is working fine on mobile, issue is only on desktop users surprisingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I inspect your website the problem is that div: **ezoic-pub-ad-placeholder-136**
if delete that all website work.
That div contain google ads.

Comment: Thanks for swift response, i even suspected and excluded this page in Ezoic already and my old AdSense ads started appearing but still issue exists! Let me check if i can remove Ezoic wrappers in code as you pointed it above.

Comment: Can you acept my answer?

Comment: Great point @Simone, it started working by commenting specific Ad code you spotted. Surprisingly all it worked well in past and issue is on fly, so i couldn't figure out so easily. Need to be more careful with 3rd party Ad codes it seems, a lesson for me. You saved my life as well my audience.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't reproduce your issue but you have lot of styles problems on 1920px screens

Comment: Agreed, it's in renovation, anyway thanks for the heads up!